# how we can go to child components in next button and back to parent components prev button in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 2 components a parent and a child. I want to show child component on parent's `next` button and parents component on child's `previous` button.

How can i do this?

Now I can call child component in next button but if i click the child component's prev button then parent component is not coming. How can i call parent component?

This is my parent component

```
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-flex> 
      <div v-if="response.inputType == 'radio'"  v-model="response.next" class="radio radio-success"
      v-bind:id="response.id" >
      <input  type="radio" v-bind:id="'option'+ response.id"  v-bind:name="index"
      v-bind:next="response.next"
      v-bind:rules="[v => !!v || 'You must agree to continue!']" v-bind:value="response.option" v-model="question.userResponses"
      v-on:click="updateResponses" v-bind:checked="question.userResponses">
      <label v-bind:for="'option'+ response.id"  >
        {{response.option}}
      </label>
    </div>
    <v-btn color="info" v-bind:id="question.prev" v-if="currentQuestion > 0"
      v-on:click="goToPreviousQuestion(e)" >prev</v-btn>
      <v-btn color="success"
      v-on:click="goToNextQuestion()">Next</v-btn>
    </v-flex>
  </v-form>
  <child v-if="showsubchild">
  </child>
</template>

<script>
  import child from '../components/child'
  components: {
    child
  }
  methods: {
    goToNextQuestion() {
      this.showsubchild=true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

[image]

and this is my child component

[image]

```
<div>
  <div v-if="response.inputType == 'radio'"  
    v-model="response.next" 
    class="radio radio-success"
    v-bind:id="response.currentQuestion" >
    <input  type="radio" 
      v-bind:id="'child'+ response.currentQuestion"  
      v-bind:name="index"
      v-bind:value="response.option" v-model="question.userResponses"
      v-bind:checked="question.userResponses">
    <label v-bind:for="'child'+ response.currentQuestion"  >
      {{response.option}}
    </label>
  </div>
  <v-btn color="info"
    v-on:click="prev(e)" >
      prev
  </v-btn>
  <v-btn color="success"
    v-on:click="next()">
      Next
  </v-btn>
  <main if="showPerent"></main>
</div>

<script> 
  import main from '../components/survey' 

  export default {
    name: "create", 
    props: ['my-props'],
    components: {
      main,
    },
    methods: {
      next(){
        this.showPerent=true,
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: In your child component you have written `if="showPerent"` instead of `v-if="showPerent"`

Comment: sorry by mistake missing v-if i have already add. but its not working

Comment: `prev()` method is not defined on child component?